# How to use the method name in live template variables?

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm. I want to use the method name from the PHP class in the Live Template variable. But I didn't find the function for it on the page [PhpStorm live template variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/template-variables.html).

Is there a way to insert the method name into the template?

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @Route(path="/profile", name="profile")
 */
public function profile(): Response
{
    return $this->render("app/profile/$HOW_TO_INSERT_METHOD_NAME_HERE$.html.twig");
}
```

Comment: I think this should be fairly easy by just using the same variable that is in the template for the method name itself. Can you post what your template looks like please?

Answer (score 1):

This is not symfony specific but you can use the `__METHOD__` constant. This will also include the class name though. Use `__FUNCTION__` to only get the name of the method itself.

See [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#57033) in the docs.

So like this:

```
return $this->render("app/profile/" . __FUNCTION__ . ".html.twig");
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/mu5qB

Comment: Not working. I need function like jsMethodName() for PHP.

Comment: See page https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/template-variables.html

Comment: @F.Tomas ohh, I just realize that you mean for a templae in PHPStorm. Sorry. What hinders you from just adding the same placeholder again that there is in use for the method name?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't available for PHP, unfortunately. Here's a link to a corresponding feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43488. Feel free to vote for or comment it in order to get notified about its updates.